# In-store iPhone 5 battery replacement?

Tags: battery, iphone, apple-store

I have an iPhone 5 that's eligible for Apple's [battery replacement program](https://www.apple.com/uk/support/iphone5-battery/). I haven't actually had any trouble with it, but I suppose I should take advantage of the offer before it expires. There are two Apple stores in the area, so I'd prefer to take the phone to one of them. But the web page doesn't actually say whether battery replacements are done on site or how long the process takes.

What should I expect here? Would Apple replace the battery while I wait? Would they ask me to leave the phone a few hours or overnight? I don't imagine they'd swap it for another phone, if only because they wouldn't have the original iPhone 5 in stock at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a battery replaced on the day after iPhone 6 launch and the process took 50 minutes door to door. (Entering the store to leaving). We did have a reservation and chose to stay past the "50 minutes" to let the iCloud restore finish and get key apps from the in store cache / fast internet.

I would expect you might get in and out 10 minutes quicker on a less busy day and could wait twice that if several phones were ahead of you to have batteries replaced.

Comment: Apple does have iPhone 5 service parts in stock in addition to batteries. Unless there's a reason to swap the whole device you should expect just the battery to be replaced.